# Gatling and variations in csv-file (feeder)

Tags: csv, gatling

Having this exec in Gatling:

```
  .exec(http("Sykdomsinfo")
  .get("https://xxx/contentapi/v1/xxx")
  .headers(headers_1)
  .queryParam("Sykdomtilstand","${sykdomtilstand}")
  .queryParam("Maalgruppe","${maalgruppe}")
  .check(status.is(expected = 200)))
```

and using feeder like this:

```
 .feed(csv("magnus/ContentAPI.csv").circular)
```

and the csv-file looking like this:

```
sykdomtilstand,maalgruppe
35489007,133936004
11381005,
363354003
```

I weant to run a simulation that for some users execute the request using two parameters (the first line in csv-file) while other users only execute wit one parameter. I want to simulate different and randomly.

What would be the best approach to accomplish this? I understand that it wont work as it stands now because of the unbalanced csv-file structure.

Answer (score 0):

May be a csv like below can help. As passing `&` does not make any change in the URL.

```
sykdomtilstand,maalgruppe
35489007,133936004
11381005,&
363354003,&
```